# How to resolve an error "Non-zero exit code (1)" while installing bootstrap package for a flask project in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pip

How to resolve an error "Non-zero exit code (1)" while installing bootstrap package for a flask project in pycharm

I am trying following command in flask in pycharm to install a bootstrap package required for my project.

**here is what I am writing:**

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
```

However, this gives the following error message:

```
*Collecting Bootstrap*

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Bootstrap (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Bootstrap
```

I am new to programming, also very new to learning flask web framework. Any help here will be highly appreciated. Thanks and have a nice weekend.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAEoa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following from commandline. If you are using virtualenv make sure you have activated your environment.

```
pip install flask-bootstrap
```

Also `from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap` is deprecated now, try using `from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I am sorry I don't know whether virtualenv is activated or not. Actually, I don't know how to install it on Microsoft windows too. I am using Pycharm professional and I am working in a flask project in it. By the way I have used flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap command too, but it gives the same error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I activated the virtualenv too. However, this time a different error:

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
  "The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Bootstrap (from versions: )."

Comment: On stackoverflow, we have to create another question if you come up to another problem. Please create another question so that I can help. Thanks